# How do I set the position of where this TextBox is displayed?

Tags: python, textbox, position, pygame

I'm fairly new to pygame and was wondering how I can choose the position of where this text box would be displayed, because right now it is always displaying the textbox in the same position.
Ideally, I'd call the function like so: `"function("Hi, how are you", (x,y))`, though I'm not sure how to implement this.

(I've looked around and I cant find any answers on `stackoverflow` or `reddit` and found nothing).

```
def textBox(Question, Position):
    #screen.fill((255,255,255))# fill the screen w/ white
    question = eztext.Input(maxlength=100, color=black, prompt=Question)#Create an input with max length 45.
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() # create the pygame clock
    run = True
    while run == True:
        clock.tick(30) # make sure the program is running at 30 fps
        events = pygame.event.get() # events for txtbx
        for event in events:
            if event.type == QUIT: # close it if x button is pressed
                return
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RETURN:
                    textBox.userResponse = question.value
                    run = False
        screen.fill((255,255,255)) # clear the screen
        question.update(events) # update txtbx
        question.draw(screen) # blit txtbx on the sceen
        pygame.display.flip() # refresh the display
```

Comment: I see that you are using eztext.  I don't know much about this, but I do know that it would be helpful if you plainly didn't use it.  I would make a textbox library myself (it's really easy, trust me).  If you then use screen.blit to place the resulting surface, you can specify the coordinates.  Take a look at the pygame.font documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple method of creating a text render function :

```
def RenderText(Text, Font, Target, X, Y, R, G, B): # The target is your screen
    """"Text , font, target surface, X, Y, 
    and color (RGB)"""
    RenderedText = Font.render(Text, True, (R, G, B))
    Target.blit(RenderedText, (X, Y))
```

---

To use it :
Load font :

```
default_font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
```

See [the wiki](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) for font customization

Apply in your loop :

```
... # Loop Stuff

# I assume that your screen is named `screen`         X   Y   Color in RGB
RenderText('Hi, how are you?', default_font, screen, 50, 50, 255, 255, 255)
# Experiment with all the above args
```

I'm not using your `eztext` class, but try this method, it's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Get [source code of eztext](http://pygame.org/project-EzText-920-.html), open in editor and you will see what you can do:

```
question = eztext.Input(x=10, y=20, ...)
```

or

```
question.set_pos(10, 20)
```

---

Source code:

```
class Input:
    """ A text input for pygame apps """
    def __init__(self, **options):
        """ Options: x, y, font, color, restricted, maxlength, prompt """
        self.options = Config(options, ['x', '0'], ['y', '0'], ['font', 'pygame.font.Font(None, 32)'],
                              ['color', '(0,0,0)'], ['restricted', '\'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&\\\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\''],
                              ['maxlength', '-1'], ['prompt', '\'\''])
        self.x = self.options.x; self.y = self.options.y
        self.font = self.options.font
        self.color = self.options.color
        self.restricted = self.options.restricted
        self.maxlength = self.options.maxlength
        self.prompt = self.options.prompt; self.value = ''
        self.shifted = False

    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        """ Set the position to x, y """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

---

To render text

- choose font and size

  ```
  font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
  ```
- render text as pygame.surface.Surface()

  ```
  text = font.render("Hello World", 1, (255,0,0))
  ```
- display in position (10,20)

  ```
  surface.blit(text, (10, 20))
  ```

You can use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position

- create rect with size of text

  ```
  text_rect = text.get_rect()
  ```
- change position

  ```
  text_rect.x = 10
  text_rect.y = 20
  ```
- or

  ```
  text_rect.topleft = (10, 20)
  ```
- or center on screen (or on other surface like button)

  ```
  text_rect.cetner = screen.get_rect().center
  ```
- display using rect

  ```
  surface.blit(text, text_rect)
  ```